# How do you prove the inequality $x^2+y^2+z^2-y(x+z)>0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

This actually comes out of a matrix multiplication of $x^TAx$, but when you multiply it out, you get the following.

$x^2+y^2+z^2-y(x+z)>0$

I just can't figure out how to actually prove that that inequality holds for all $x,y,z\neq0$.  Also, note that this is for a linear algebra class, so I don't think you're allowed to use derivatives.  Also, in case it is important, here are the original matrices used to get that inequality.

$A=$ $
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 2 \end{array} \right)$

and $x = \left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z\ \end{array}\right)$

Comment: hint multiply by $2$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion

Answer (score 6):

The inequality is

$$\frac12\left(x^2 + (x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + z^2 \right) > 0.$$

It is easy to see that that holds for all real $(x,y,z) \neq (0,0,0)$.

A more linear-algebra-y way is to consider the minors of $A$; we have $2 > 0$,

$$\begin{align}
\det \begin{pmatrix}2 & -1\\-1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} &= 2^2 - (-1)^2 = 3 > 0\\
\det \begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 & 0\\ -1 & 2 & -1\\ 0 & -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} &= 8 + 0 + 0 - 0 - 2 - 2 = 4 > 0,
\end{align}$$

so $A$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 4):

One can see that the matrix $A$ has three positive eigenvalues. This means it is positive definite, and hence $x^{T} A x$ is positive for any non-zero $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $(x-y)^2 \geq 0$, it follows easily that $xy \leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)$.  Similarly, $yz \leq \frac{1}{2}(y^2+z^2)$.  That gives you

$$x^2+y^2+z^2-y(x+z) \geq \frac{1}{2}(x^2+z^2).  $$

The right-hand-side above is positive unless $x=z=0$.  But if $x=z=0$, then

$$ x^2+y^2+z^2-y(x+z)=y^2,$$

and that will be positive unless $x=y=z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1 \end{array} \right) =
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 2 \end{array} \right)
$$

The eigenvalues of
$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \end{array} \right)
$$
are $4,1,1,$ so positive definite. The operation $B \mapsto P^T B P$ for symmetric $B$ and $P \in SL_3 \mathbb Z$ gives an "equivalent" quadratic form; the eigenvalues do not stay the same, the eigenvectors do not stay the same, but positivity is preserved, because
$$ x^T P^T B P x = (Px)^T B (Px)  $$ Note that $Px=0$ if and only if $x=0.$

```
value = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - y(x + z)
   value             x     y     z
     0               0     0     0
     1               0     1     1
     2               1     2     1
     3               0     2     1
     4               0     2     2
     5               1     3     2
     6               1     2     3
     7               0     3     2
     8               2     4     2
     9               0     3     3
    10               1     4     3
    11               1     3     4
    12               0     4     2
    13               0     4     3
    15               1     5     3
    16               0     4     4
    17               1     5     4
    18               1     4     5
    19               0     5     3
    20               2     6     4
    21               0     5     4
    22               1     6     3
    23               1     6     4
    24               2     4     6
    25               0     5     5
    26               1     6     5
    27               0     6     3
    28               0     6     4
    29               2     7     5
    31               0     6     5
    32               4     8     4
    33               1     7     5
    34               1     4     7
    35               1     5     7
    36               0     6     6
    37               0     7     4
    38               1     6     7
    39               0     7     5
    40               2     8     6
    41               1     8     4
    42               1     8     5
    43               0     7     6
    44               2     6     8
    45               1     8     6
    47               1     6     8
    48               0     8     4
    49               0     8     5
    50               1     8     7
    51               1     7     8
    52               0     8     6
    53               1     9     5
    54               3    10     5
    55               1     9     6
    57               0     8     7
    58               1     6     9
    59               1     9     7
    60               2    10     6
    61               0     9     5
    63               0     9     6
    64               0     8     8
    65               1     9     8
    66               1    10     5
    67               0     9     7
    68               2    10     8
    69               2     7    10
    70               1    10     7
    71               1     6    10
    72               2     8    10
    73               0     9     8
    74               5    12     7
    75               0    10     5
    76               0    10     6
    77               1     8    10
    79               0    10     7
    80               4    12     8
    81               0     9     9
    82               1    10     9
    83               1    11     7
    84               0    10     8
    85               2    11     9
    86               1     6    11
    87               1    11     8
    88               2    12     6
    89               2    12     7
    90               1     8    11
    91               0    11     6
    92               2    12     8
    93               0    11     7
    95               1     9    11
    96               4     8    12
    97               0    11     8
    98               1    12     7
    99               2     7    12
   100               0    10    10
   101               1    12     8
   102               1    10    11
   103               0    11     9
   104               2    12    10
   105               1     8    12
   106               1    12     9
   107               2    13     8
   108               0    12     6
   109               0    12     7
   111               0    11    10
   112               0    12     8
   113               1    12    10
   114               3    14     7
   115               1    13     7
   116               4    14    10
   117               0    12     9
   118               3    14     9
   119               2     9    13
   121               0    11    11
   122               1    12    11
   123               1    11    12
   124               0    12    10
   125               1     9    13
   127               0    13     7
   128               8    16     8
   129               0    13     8
   130               1    10    13
   131               4    15    10
   132               2    14    10
   133               0    13     9
   134               1    14     7
   135               1    14     8
   136               2     8    14
   137               1    11    13
   138               1    14     9
   139               0    13    10
   140               2    10    14
   141               1     8    14
   143               1    14    10
   144               0    12    12
   145               1    13    12
   146               1    12    13
   147               0    14     7
   148               0    14     8
   149               2    15    10
   150               1    14    11
   151               0    14     9
   152               2    12    14
   153               1    11    14
   154               3    16     9
   155               1    15     8
   156               0    14    10
   157               0    13    12
   159               1    14    12
   160               4    16    12
   161               1    15    10
   162               1     8    15
   163               0    14    11
   164               2    16     8
   165               2    16     9
   166               1    10    15
   167               1    15    11
   168               2    16    10
   169               0    15     8
   170               1    14    13
   171               0    15     9
   172               0    14    12
   173               2    16    11
   175               0    15    10
   176               4    12    16
   177               1    16     8
   178               1    16     9
   179               2     9    16
   180               2    16    12
   181               0    15    11
   182               5    18    11
   183               0    14    13
   185               1    15    13
   186               1    16    11
   187               1    13    15
   188               2    12    16
   189               0    15    12
   191               1    11    16
   192               0    16     8
   193               0    16     9
   194               5    18    13
   195               2    13    16
   196               0    16    10
   197               1    15    14
   198               1    14    15
   199               0    15    13
   200               2    16    14
   201               0    16    11
   202               1    16    13
   203               1    17    10
   204               2    14    16
   205               1    13    16
   207               1    17    11
   208               0    16    12
   209               1     9    17
   210               1    10    17
   211               0    15    14
   212               2    18    10
   213               1    17    12
   214               3    18    13
   215               1    14    16
   216               6    20    10
   217               0    17     9
   218               1    12    17
   219               0    17    10
   220               2    18    12
   221               1    17    13
   223               0    17    11
   225               0    15    15
   226               1    18     9
   227               1    18    10
   228               0    16    14
   229               0    17    12
   230               1    18    11
   231               1    17    14
   232               2    12    18
   233               2    15    17
   234               1    14    17
   235               1    18    12
   236               2    18    14
   237               0    17    13
   239               2    19    11
   240               4    20    12
   241               0    16    15
   242               1    18    13
   243               0    18     9
   244               0    18    10
   245               1    15    17
   246               5    14    19
   247               0    18    11
   249               2    19    13
   250               3    20    11
   251               1    18    14
   252               0    18    12
   253               1    19    10
   255               1    19    11
   256               0    16    16
   257               1    17    16
   258               1    16    17
   259               0    18    13
   260               2    18    16
   261               2    13    19
   262               1    18    15
   263               1    11    19
   264               2    20    10
   265               1    19    13
   266               1    12    19
   267               2    19    15
   268               0    18    14
   269               4    21    13
   271               0    19    10
   272               4    20    16
   273               0    19    11
   274               3    20    15
   275               1    18    16
   276               4    14    20
   277               0    19    12
   278               1    14    19
   279               0    18    15
   280               2    20    14
   281               1    20    10
   282               1    20    11
   283               0    19    13
   284               2    12    20
   285               1    20    12
   287               1    15    19
   288               4    16    20
   289               0    17    17
   290               1    20    13
   291               0    19    14
   292               0    18    16
   293               1    12    20
   294               5    22    15
   295               1    19    16
   296              10    24    14
   297               1    20    14
   298               1    16    19
   299               2    21    13
   300               0    20    10
   301               0    20    11
   303               1    14    20
   304               0    20    12
   305               2    21    14
   306               1    20    15
   307               0    18    17
   308               2    16    20
   309               0    20    13
   310               3    22    13
   311               1    21    11
   313               0    19    16
   314               5    22    17
   315               2    13    21
   316               0    20    14
   317               1    21    13
   319               2    17    20
   320               8    24    16
   321               1    16    20
   322               1    12    21
   323               1    21    14
   324               0    18    18
   325               0    20    15
   326               1    18    19
   327               0    19    17
   328               2    20    18
   329               5    15    22
   330               1    20    17
   331               0    21    11
   332               2    22    14
   333               0    21    12
   335               2    21    17
   336               0    20    16
   337               0    21    13
   338               5    24    13
   339               2    22    15
   340               4    22    18
   341               1    21    16
   342               1    22    11
   343               0    21    14
   344               2    12    22
   345               1    20    18
   346               1    22    13
   347               1    18    20
   348               2    22    16
   349               0    20    17
   351               0    21    15
   352               4    24    12
   353               1    21    17
   354               7    16    23
   355               1    13    22
   356               4    24    14
   357               1    17    21
   358               1    22    15
   359               1    14    22
   360               2    16    22
   361               0    21    16
   362               1    20    19
   363               0    22    11
   364               0    22    12
   365               1    15    22
   367               0    22    13
   368               4    24    16
   369               2    19    21
   370               1    18    21
   371               5    25    14
   372               0    22    14
   373               0    21    17
   374               5    18    23
   375               1    23    12
   377               1    23    13
   378               1    22    17
   379               0    22    15
   380               2    18    22
   381               0    20    19
   383               1    21    19
   384               8    16    24
   385               1    19    21
   386               1    12    23
   387               0    21    18
   388               0    22    16
   389               2    24    13
   390               1    14    23
   391               1    22    18
   392               2    24    14
   393               2    19    22
   394               3    24    17
   395               1    23    16
   396               4    14    24
   397               0    23    12
   399               0    23    13
   400               0    20    20
   401               1    21    20
   402               1    20    21
   403               0    23    14
   404               2    24    16
   405               1    23    17
   406               1    22    19
   407               2    18    23
   408               2    20    22
   409               0    23    15
   410               1    24    13
   411               1    17    23
   412               0    22    18
   413               1    24    14
   415               2    15    24
   416               4    24    20
   417               0    23    16
   418               1    24    15
   419               2    19    23
   420               2    16    24
   421               0    21    20
   422               1    18    23
   423               1    22    20
   424               2    24    18
   425               1    24    16
   426               5    16    25
   427               0    23    17
   428               4    26    16
   429               2    25    15
   431               1    23    19
   432               0    24    12
   433               0    24    13
   434               1    24    17
   435               1    19    23
   436               0    24    14
   437               2    24    19
   438               3    26    13
   439               0    23    18
   441               0    24    15
   442               1    22    21
   443               1    21    22
   444               0    22    20
   445               1    25    13
   447               1    25    14
   448               0    24    16
   449               2    21    23
   450               1    20    23
   451               1    25    15
   452               2    24    20
   453               0    23    19
   454               3    26    17
   455               4    27    14
   456               6    28    14
   457               0    24    17
   458               1    24    19
   459               2    26    13
   460               2    26    14
   461               1    15    25
   463               0    22    21
   464               8    28    20
   465               1    25    17
   466               1    16    25
   467               1    21    23
   468               0    24    18
   469               0    25    13
   470              11    30    17
   471               0    25    14
   472               6    28    18
   473               1    24    20
   474               3    26    19
   475               0    25    15
   476               4    18    26
   477               1    20    24
   479               2    25    20
   481               0    25    16
   482               1    26    13
   483               1    26    14
   484               0    22    22
   485               1    23    22
   486               1    26    15
   487               0    23    21
   488               2    24    22
   489               0    25    17
   490               1    24    21
   491               1    26    16
   492               2    22    24
   493               1    21    24
   495               1    14    26
   496               0    24    20
   497               1    15    26
   498               1    26    17
   499               0    25    18
MISSING:
   14   30   46   56   62   78   94  110  120  126  142  158
  174  184  190  206  222  224  238  248  254  270  286  302
  312  318  334  350  366  376  382  398  414  430  440  446
  462  478  480  494  
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Comment: I read your comment and I'm curious - why not just use Sylvester's Criterion?

Comment: @StefanSmith, as far as this site, it is because I already put a comment about that and other people gave roughly that answer. Part 2: I have published in integral ternary quadratic forms, and recognized that the given form (well, $1/2$ times it) was "equivalent" to a known "regular" form, $ f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + yz + zx + xy.  $ And I have software for instantly finding me the basis change to go between forms. See the 913 paper with Kaplansky and Schiemann at http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/bib.html Put another way: I was showing off.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is easier to look at the [Gershgorin circle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)

to realize that this matrix $A$ has non negative eigenvalues (you do not need to compute them actually), in addition, since all the diagonal elements are strictly dominant excepting only one, then $A$ is invertible, therefore 0 is not an eigenvalue of $A$, hence $A$ is positive definite, which also means that $x^TAx > 0, x\neq0$

The nice part of this method is that it only takes you three sums xD

Comment: I thought the diagonal elements had to strictly dominate the off-diagonal row sums, otherwise it could be positive semi-definite?

Comment: If all the diagonal elements are strictly dominant excepting one being only dominant, the matrix is invertible. Is an extension of the Theorem, you can check it in Theorem 6.1.11 Matrix Analysis (Horn and Johnson). Therefore 0 is not an eigenvalue of this $A$, hence it can only be positive definite.

Comment: I have edited my answer with your remark, thanks @WillJagy

Comment: Good. I recently got a copy of Horn and Johnson, I can go look later.